# MATCH AGAINST gives 0 for 'Depression' against 'Depressed'

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

My MATCH AGAINST is otherwise working, I am just curious what is going on under the hood that

```
SELECT `rfv`, MATCH `rfv` AGAINST('Depressed') FROM `rfvs`
```

returns a match score of 0 when rfv is 'Depression'.  I just think it should be higher. Clearly not a perfect match, but the best match it gives me against a list of medical complaints (no lie) is 'Anal-rectal itching'

Comment: What aboue "against 'depress'"?  Or 'depress*' ?

Comment: The problem is these are two fixed datasets that I am using match against to harmonize these little inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a feature of some search engines called "stemming". It means different forms of the same word match. Like plurals, gerunds, conjugations, or other suffixes.

MySQL's fulltext indexing does not support stemming. They have a worklog on file, but it hasn't been implemented. https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2423 The worklog is unassigned, and it's marked for implementation in MySQL 7.1, which dates the worklog from quite a few years ago, because there never was a MySQL 7.x version released. They skipped from 5.7 directly to 8.0.

The feature request was filed in 2005: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15085 Feel free to vote for that issue by logging in to the bug tracker and clicking "Affects Me". After you do that, you may have to wait between 2 and 20 years for it to be implemented.

Or you could copy your searchable data into another search engine that supports stemming, for example [Apache Solr](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html#stemming).

Comment: I imagine match against used letter similarities/ dissimilarities to get a score. A score of 0 seems really weird when many letter positions are similar.

Comment: Well, you know what they say about when you assume...